# Why should we use `realloc` if we need a `tmp buffer`

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

As far of my concern if `realloc` fails we loose the information and `realloc` set the Buffer(pointer) to `NULL`

Consider de following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    char *ptr = malloc(256);

    if (!ptr){
        printf("Error, malloc\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    strcpy(ptr, "Michi");

    ptr = realloc (ptr, 1024 * 102400000uL); /* I ask for a big chunk here to make realloc to fail */

    if (!ptr){
        printf("Houston we have a Problem\n");
    }

    printf("PTR = %s\n", ptr);

    if (ptr){
        free(ptr);
        ptr = NULL;
    }
}
```

And the output of course is:

```
Houston we have a Problem
PTR = (null)
```

I just lost the information inside `ptr`.

Now to fix this we should use a temporary buffer(pointer) before to see if we get that chunk of memory and if we get it we can use it, if not we still have the main buffer(pointer) safe.

Now please consider the following program, where instead of calling `realloc` I call `malloc` on a temporary buffer(pointer):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    char *ptr = malloc(256);
    char *tmpPTR = NULL;

    if (!ptr){
        printf("Error, malloc\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    strcpy(ptr, "Michi");

    tmpPTR = malloc (1024 * 102400000uL);
    if (tmpPTR){
        strcpy(tmpPTR, ptr);
        strcat(tmpPTR, " - Aloha");

        if (ptr){
            free(ptr);
            ptr = NULL;
        }
    }else{
        printf("Malloc failed on tmpPTR\n\n");
    }


    if (ptr){
        printf("PTR = %s\n", ptr);

        free(ptr);
        ptr = NULL;
    }else if (tmpPTR){
        printf("tmpPTR = %s\n", tmpPTR);

        free(tmpPTR);
        ptr = NULL;
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Malloc failed on tmpPTR

PTR = Michi
```

Now why should I ever use `realloc`? 
Is there any benefit of using `realloc` instead of `malloc` based on this context?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. If [`realloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html) fails, it does return `NULL`, but the buffer is unchanged (and still perfectly valid to use). You're simply doing it wrong. Use a temporary pointer instead.

Comment: Yes, I meant direct assigment, but I still need a tmpBuffer. So Why should I use Realloc? That was the Question.

Comment: Down Voter please explain?

Comment: @Michi The question is kind of a confusing mess. If you want to know what to do when `realloc` returns NULL, just ask that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No I don't need that. I already know that. I just don't find a reason why should I use `realloc` instead of calling `malloc` again. I need an example where you need `realloc` and where `malloc` doesn't work. This was my Question.

Comment: @Michi Your entire question is based on a misunderstanding. You never "need" `realloc`, it's just more efficient because it can avoid having to copy the data and allocate a second block. (And that shows why this is a bad question. It tangles a misunderstanding of how to use `realloc` into a question of when to use it based on that misunrderstanding.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz YES, that was my point. If i ever really need `realloc`.

Comment: @Michi And the answer is -- once you correct your misunderstanding of how to handle its failure, there's no reason to ask that question. There would be no reason not to use it. (Your question is basically "why should I use `realloc` when it's so hard to use. And the answer is "It's not hard to use, you're just doing it wrong. So use `realloc` all the time")

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and for that i got `2` down votes. I love SO.

Comment: @Michi Down votes on a question aren't judging the person asking the question. They're just judging the value of the question. You got the answer you needed, I hope. You just happened to encounter the issue in a way that lead to a poor question, so we downvote it so that it won't confuse others.

Comment: @Michi: As an example, I show how I normally use `realloc()`, without ever needing `malloc()`. The fact is, you don't actually need `malloc()`, ever, because `malloc(size)` and `realloc(NULL, size)` are equivalent. However, with `realloc()` you can *grow* a dynamically allocated buffer. In fact, often the C library can do that without copying any memory. My answer shows exactly why you would wish to do that -- as an example, when reading unknown-length inputs.

Comment: Also, I agree with David Schwartz: the downvotes are to the question, not to the asker. (I do not usually vote, though; I just "push" (often to the limit of almost flaming) the asker to reformat their question until the true, interesting question underneath is uncovered.) I suspect there is a good question underneath this question, too, relating to the use case differences with `malloc()` and `realloc()`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I never intended to ask about performances between `malloc` and `realloc` I wonted to know if (a demo maybe) you can do something with `realloc` and doesn't work with `malloc`. I will try to search after `realloc` implementation.

Comment: @Michi: That is exactly what my answer shows! I shall add some explanatory stuff into it.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with how you use `realloc`. You don't have to assign the result of `realloc` to the same pointer that you re-allocate. And as you point out it even poses a problem if the `realloc` fails. If you immediately assign the result to `ptr` then indeed you lose the previous buffer when something goes wrong. However, if you assign the result of `realloc` to `tmpPTR`, then `ptr` remains fine, even if the `realloc` fails. Use `realloc` as follows:

```
char * ptr = malloc(256);
if(!ptr){
    return 1;
}

char * tmpPTR = realloc(ptr, 512);
if(!tmpPTR){
    printf("Houston, we have a problem");
    // ptr is fine
}else{
    ptr = tmpPTR;
}

// ptr is realloc()ed
```

In the above code, `tmpPTR` is not a new (temporary) buffer, but just a (temporary) pointer. If the `realloc` is succesful it points to the same buffer (but possibly in a different location), and if it fails it is `NULL`. `realloc` doesn't always need to allocate a new buffer, but may be able to change the existing one to fit the new size. But if it fails, the original buffer will not be changed.

If you use `malloc` with a temporary buffer, then (for this example) you need at least 256 + 512 = 768 bytes and you always need to copy the old data. `realloc` may be able to re-use the old buffer so copying is not necessary and you don't use more memory than requested.

You can use your `malloc` approach, but `realloc` is almost always more efficient.

Comment: You are missing the `else ptr = tmp;`. That's crucial, given that, after a successful `realloc`, the old buffer may not be valid anymore.

Comment: Thats the whole point. To use `realloc` I need a temporary buffer. So why should I use `realloc` instead malloc? This is my Question. Please read my question again

Comment: @Michi: that's not a temporary buffer, it's just a temporary pointer. Anyhow, as you see handling correctly `realloc` is way less work than your proposed solution. Besides, `realloc` doesn't necessarily copy data around - if the original block `malloc` gave to you was big enough, it turns into a no-op, thus having potentially better performance. Also, if the original block has enough space free after it, it can just be "logically" resized, which again is a cheap operation (and you may not have enough address space for both the old and the new buffer).

Comment: @MatteoItalia You right :), but lets stay to my Question please.

Comment: @Michi That's the answer -- you don't need a temporary buffer. And if you use one, and `realloc` fails, you now have two buffers with the same data -- one more than you need.

Comment: @Kninnug Your Answer doesn't answer my Question. You try to explain me that I need a temporary pointer instead of direct assigment.  Me, I was asking why should I use `realloc` if I can do the same job with `malloc` as long as I need a temporary pointer.

Comment: @Michi I hope my edits clarified it a bit more. The point is: you don't strictly need `realloc`, but it is usually far more efficient and less code.

Comment: @Michi "I was asking why should I use realloc" - that's not the same question you've been asking throughout this post. Ex: you asked up in general comment "I need an example where you need realloc...".  In your actual question you asked ,"Is there any benefit of using realloc...". There's a big difference between "need" and "should use" or "any benefit". Thus the splay of answers and corrections. The fact is, used *properly*, a `realloc` strategy *can be* more memory efficient. If you rather choose not to do that and potentially reap that benefit, that's all it is: a choice.

Comment: @WhozCraig That was my Question and your comment answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

The `realloc` scheme is simple. You do not need a separate call to `malloc`. For example if you initially have `256` bytes allocated for `ptr`, simply use a counter (or index, `i` below) to keep track of how much of the memory within the block allocated to `ptr` has been used, and when the counter reaches the limit (1 less than the max for 0-based indexes, or 2 less than the max if you are using `ptr` as a *string*), `realloc`.

Below shows a scheme where you are simply adding `256` additional bytes to `ptr` each time the allocation limit is reached:

```
int i = 0, max = 256;
char *ptr = malloc(max);

/* do whatever until i reaches 255 */

if (i + 1 >= max) {
    void *tmp = realloc (ptr, max + 256);
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc - memory exhausted.\n")
        /* handle error */
    }
    ptr = tmp;
    max += 256;
}
```

***note:*** your `handle error` can exit whatever loop you are in to preserve the existing data in `ptr`. You do not need to exit at that point.

Answer (score 1):

> Now to fix this we should use a temporary buffer(pointer) before to see if we get that chunk of memory and if we get it we can use it, if not we still have the main buffer(pointer) safe.

That not only doesn't help, it makes things worse because now you no longer have the pointer to the block you tried to reallocate. So how can you `free` it?

So it:

1. Wastes memory.
2. Require an extra allocate, copy, and free.
3. Makes the `realloc` more likely to fail because of 1.
4. Leaks memory since the pointer to the block you tried to reallocate is lost.

So no, that's not a good way to handle `realloc` returning NULL. Save the original pointer when you call `realloc` so you can handle failure sanely. The point of `realloc` to save you from having to manage two copies of the data and to avoid even making them when that's possible. So let `realloc` do this work for you whenever you can.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of `realloc` over `malloc` is that it may be able to extend the original dynamic memory area so without the need to copy all the previous elements; you **can't** do that with `malloc`<sup>1</sup>. And whether this optimization is available costs no work to you.

---

Let's assume you have a previously allocated pointer:

```
char *some_string = malloc(size); // assume non-NULL
```

Then

```
if (realloc_needed) {
      char *tmp = realloc(some_string, new_size);

     if ( tmp == NULL ) 
          // handle error
     else
         some_string = tmp; // (1)
```

At (1), you update the old pointer with the new one. Two things can happen: the address has effectively changed (and the elements been *automatically* copied) or it hasn't - you don't really care. Either way, your data is now at `some_string`.

---

<sup>Only the actual implementation (OS / libc) knows whether it's possible to enlarge the block: you don't get to see it, it's an implementation detail. You can however check your implementation's code and see how it's implemented.</sup>

Comment: `...you can't do that with malloc. ` Please provide an example.

Comment: You mean [something like this](http://ideone.com/NYp1os)? `realloc` works different? Probably `realloc` uses `memcpy` but this is another Story

Comment: @michi The advantage is that `realloc` has quite some chance to evade the `memcpy` way if the underlying implementation supports it (like growing the original chunk or paging in memory where none was before) because it knows the inner workings of the memory management. Most modern operating systems wouldn't need to `memcpy` in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically [`malloc(size)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) that is unneeded, because [`realloc(NULL, size)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html) performs the exact same task.

I often read inputs of indeterminate length. As in the following function example, I rarely use `malloc()`, and instead use `realloc()` extensively:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct record {
    /* fields in each record */
};

struct table {
    size_t         size;   /* Number of records allocated */
    size_t         used;   /* Number of records in table */
    struct record  item[]; /* C99 flexible array member */
};

#define MAX_ITEMS_PER_READ 1

struct table *read_table(FILE *source)
{
    struct table  *result = NULL, *temp;
    size_t         size = 0;
    size_t         used = 0, n;
    int            err = 0;

    /* Read loop */
    while (1) {

        if (used + MAX_ITEMS_PER_READ > size) {
            /* Array size growth policy.
             * Some suggest doubling the size,
             * or using a constant factor.
             * Here, the minimum is
             *     size = used + MAX_ITEMS_PER_READ;
            */
            const size_t  newsize = 2*MAX_ITEMS_PER_READ + used + used / 2;

            temp = realloc(result, sizeof (struct table) + 
                                   newsize * sizeof (result->item[0]));
            if (!temp) {
                err = ENOMEM;
                break;
            }

            result = temp;
            size = newsize;
        }

        /* Read a record to result->item[used],
         * or up to (size-used) records starting at result->item + used.
         * If there are no more records, break.
         * If an error occurs, set err = errno, and break.
         *
         * Increment used by the number of records read: */            
        used++;
    }

    if (err) {
        free(result); /* NOTE: free(NULL) is safe. */
        errno = err;
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!used) {
        free(result);
        errno = ENODATA; /* POSIX.1 error code, not C89/C99/C11 */
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Optional: optimize table size. */
    if (used < size) {
        /* We don't mind even if realloc were to fail here. */
        temp = realloc(result, sizeof (struct table) + 
                               used * sizeof table->item[0]);
        if (temp) {
            result = temp;
            size = used;
        }
    }

    result->size = size;
    result->used = used;

    errno = 0; /* Not normally zeroed; just my style. */
    return result;
}
```

My own practical reallocation policies tend to be very conservative, limiting the size increase to a megabyte or so. There is a very practical reason for this.

On most 32-bit systems, userspace applications are limited to 2 to 4 gigabyte virtual address space. I wrote and ran simulation systems on a lot of different x86 systems (32-bit), all with 2 to 4 GB of memory. Usually, most of that memory is needed for a single dataset, which is read from disk, and manipulated in place. When the data is not in final form, it cannot be directly memory-mapped from disk, as a translation -- usually from text to binary -- is needed.

When you use `realloc()` to grow the dynamically allocated array to store such huge (on 32-bit) datasets, you are only limited by the available virtual address space (assuming there is enough memory available). (This especially applies to 32-bit applications on 64-bit systems.)

If, instead, you use `malloc()` -- i.e., when you notice your dynamically allocated array is not large enough, you `malloc()` a new one, copy the data over, and discard the old one --, *your final data set size is limited to a lesser size*, the difference depending on your exact array size growth policy. If you use the typical *double when resizing* policy, your final dataset is limited to about half (the available virtual address space, or available memory, whichever is smaller).

On 64-bit systems with lots and lots of memory, `realloc()` still matters, but is much more of a performance issue, rather than on 32-bit, where `malloc()` is a limiting factor. You see, when you use `malloc()` to allocate a completely new array, and copy the old data to the new array, the resident set size -- the actual amount of physical RAM needed by your application -- is larger; you use 50% more physical RAM to read the data than you would when using `realloc()`. You also do a lot of large memory-to-memory copies (when reading a huge dataset), which are limited to physical RAM bandwidth, and indeed slow down your application (although, if you are reading from a spinning disk, that is the actual bottleneck anyway, so it won't matter much).

The nastiest effect, and the most difficult to benchmark, are the indirect effects. Most operating systems use "free" RAM to cache recently accessed files not modified yet, and this really does decrease the wall clock time used by most workloads. (In particular, caching typical libraries and executables may shave off *seconds* from the startup time of large application suites, if the storage media is slow (ie. a spinning disk, and not a SSD).) Your memory-wasting `malloc()`-only approach gobbles up much more actual physical RAM than needed, which evicts cached, often useful, files from memory!

You might benchmark your program, and note that there is no real difference in run times between using your `malloc()`-only approach and `realloc()` approach I've shown above. But, if it works with large datasets, the users will notice that using the `malloc()`-only program *slows down other programs* much more than the `realloc()`-using program, with the same data!

So, although on 64-bit systems with lots of RAM using `malloc()` only is basically an inefficient way to approach things, on 32-bit systems it limits the size of dynamically allocated arrays when the final size is unknown beforehand. Only using `realloc()` can you there achieve the maximum possible dataset size.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong. Please do note that a pointer is not a buffer. When the function `realloc()` succeeds, it deallocates the old pointer(frees the original buffer) and return a new pointer to the new allocation(buffer), but when it fails, it leaves the old buffer intact and returns NULL.

So, you do not need a temporary buffer. You need a temporary pointer. I am going to borrow the example from kninnug, this is what you need to do:

```
char * ptr = malloc(256);
if (!ptr) {
    return 1;
}

char * tmpPTR = realloc(ptr, 512);
if (!tmpPTR) {
    printf("Houston, we have a problem");
    // ptr is fine
}
else {
    ptr = tmpPTR;
}

// ptr is realloc()ed
```

Comment: As long as the pointer points to some location where some information is stored, a pointer is a buffer,  because it doesn't just hold/points to that memory location, it also have acces to its value[s]. What ever, you are the teacher here.

Comment: @Michi I think Kninnug's answer is perfect and completely address your question.

Comment: I gave up. I'm more than one year here. I know when some one speak about the language or its personal opinion. I learn C for fun and trust me is not a language for everyone.

Comment: When I'm telling you that I need malloc an not realloc and you tell me that I should use realloc because is safer, well SO is not standing for that and also the C language is not for you. That's why exists C++, because C is not for everyone.

Comment: @Michi I don't understand what the problem is,sorry. But kninnug tells you in his last line "_you can use your malloc approach, but realloc is almost always more efficient._"...

Comment: @Michi by "I don't understand what the problem" statement, I mean I don't know why do you find the answers unsatisfactory.

Comment: It is efficient because exists. What happens if it doesn't? You move to C++ trust me. This means C, you need to create every damn thing to work. What ever, sorry because I'm wasting your time